# Nginx as reverse proxy for Docker-contained Tomcat

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, tomcat

Consider the following diagram:

[image: infrastructure diagram]

I have a Debian droplet from Digital Ocean where I need to deploy N Java applications inside individual Docker containers running a Tomcat instance.

Each image has the following Dockerfile configuration:

```
FROM tomcat:jdk8-openjdk
LABEL maintainer="admin@mail.com"
ADD webapp1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ #webapp1, webapp2,... webappN
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And is built with:

```
docker build -t webapp1 .
docker build -t webapp2 .
...
```

Each container is started with the command:

```
docker run -it -d -p 8081:8080 webapp1
docker run -it -d -p 8082:8080 webapp2
...
```

Every application works correctly and is accesible through the droplet IP address, port and application name:

```
http://123.123.123.123:8081/webapp1
http://123.123.123.123:8082/webapp2
...
```

But I need to use a domain name (without SSL for now):

```
http://example.com/webapp1
http://example.com/webapp2
...
```

So I'm using Nginx as reverse proxy to achieve this. The following is the Nginx configuration in `sites-available` folder I'm using:

**default file:**

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

**webapp1 file:**

```
# webapp1 configuration
#
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123:8081/;
  }
}
```

**webapp2 file:**

```
# webapp2 configuration
#
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123:8082/;
  }
}
```

Here's the problem, when I deployed the first application and made it accesible through the domain name (`example.com/webapp1`) it was working fine but an 404 error was produced when I try to access `example.com` (my landing page). I decided to solve this problem later and better to try to deploy a second application. It worked, webapp2 was successfully deployed and was accesible through `example.com/webapp2` but now both `example.com` and `example.com/webapp1` are giving an 404 error.

I'm a Nginx and Docker newbie. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nginx a `server` configuration block defines a single named virtual host. If you define multiple `server` blocks for the same domain, there should be a **warning** in the logs, but a single `server` block will be chosen, the others will be ignored.

What you need is multiple `location` blocks. So you need a single `sites-available/example.com` configuration (symlinked from `sites-enabled/example.com`) like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # For each web application
    location /webapp1/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://192.0.2.1:8081;
    }
}
```

**Remark**: the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers have no effect on Tomcat, unless you add:

```xml
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
```

to the Tomcat `<Host>` configuration.

Comment: Upvote. But: `sites-enabled` is "symlinked" from `sites-available` - not the other way round. Or my English is too bad to understand your wording.

Comment: @uav: yes, I meant `sites-enabled/example.com` should be a symbolic link to `site-available/example.com`. I don't know if there is a standard meaning for the non-existent verb `to symlink`. :-)

Comment: It worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway.Any idea ?

Comment: Look at the NGINX logs, the Tomcat server must be down or you provided the wrong address.